# Efficiency issues when using C99 and C11.

Tags: c, performance, visual-c++, c99

The other day I was converting a program written with C99 standard into C11. Basically the motive was to use the code with MSVC but It was written in Linux and was mostly compiled with default GCC behaviour. During the code conversion, I found out that you can not decalre variables of a function after any statement i.e. you must declare them at the top of the function.

But my question is that wouldn't it be against the efficient programming rule that variables should be declared near their use so that it maximizes the cache hits? For example, In a large function of say 200 LOC, I want to use some big static look up array at nearly the end of the function. Wouldn't declaring and initializing it just before the usage cause more cache hits?  or am I simple missing some basic point of C11 C language standard?

Comment: C2011 (I hate the name C11) allows declarations intermixed with code. *I understand Microsoft's compiler understands only C89, maybe with a few extensions.*

Comment: This is related to C89, where you cannot put declarations after statements in the same block. This requirement no longer exists in C99 and C11.

Comment: MSVC doesn't support C11.  Perhaps you meant C89?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was so into the question that I forgot what does MSVC supprt. :d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have some confusion for which version of the standard you are compiling your program. AFAIK, MSVC doesn't support any of the more recent C standards.

But to come to the core of your question, no this is not an efficiency issue. The compiler is allowed to reorder statements to its liking, as long as the observable behavior of the program doesn't change. Thus a modern compiler will always touch a new variable the latest possible before its first use.

Comment: Unless `volatile` is involved... but it's possible to have a pure declaration at the beginning of the function with no access to the variable at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt, `volatile` has not much influence on the reordering of statements, I think. It only forces a reload of an object for each expression in which it is used. What may have an influence on what the compiler can deduce is aliasing. But in general if you declare an `int` variable at the start of your program and even initialize it, the compiler can place the initialization anywhere before the first use of the variable.

Comment: Read and write of *other* variables cannot move across a volatile access either.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What kind of other variables? There is definitely no ordering imposed for reads and writes of non-volatile variables; they may not even exist in memory. For a single thread, reads and writes of volatile variables must be ordered with respect to one another, but the memory model does not impose any requirement on the order they're seen by other threads. You would need atomics to get that.

Comment: @R..: The Standard does not impose an ordering on access to non-volatile variables in the presence of `volatile`, but neither does it guarantee that an ordering is NOT imposed.  Many implementations do impose ordering and a memory fence at `volatile` accesses.  And the compiler used by the OP is one of those.  **So in practice, there IS an efficiency issue caused by moving variable initializations around in a function that also contains `volatile` variables.**

Comment: OK, your new comment clarifies things. If MSVC imposes memory fences with volatile, then it does affect efficiency. Other compilers do not to my knowledge do this.

Answer (score 2):

Where the variable declaration appears has no effect on cache behavior.  Just having a declaration doesn't touch memory.

You may need to separate out initialization into a separate assignment, however, in order to make sure you don't have an initializer causing a memory access at (near) the beginning of the function.